# How to keep app from crashing while using the subprocess in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, cmd, subprocess

Greetings to the stackoverflow community. I need some direction in how to keep my Python cmd line app from crashing when the network I'm cloning a repository from (GitHub) disconnects because many clone requests. Below is the code that I use to clone the repo. Currently, it runs fine. But, I imagine, when there are multiple people downloading the repo or something is slow about the network, I get kicked off, and my app crashes. I thought the try/except statement would prevent crashing, but to no avail:

```
 ...
 command = r'git clone git@github.com:somerepo.git'
  try:
      subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
      click.echo(cpe.output)
 ...
```

Error:

```
   Git Clone Fails - error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

   git clone http://somerepo/repo.git
   fatal: early EOF
   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   fatal: index-pack failed
   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
```

Comment: Has this actually happened, or is this just, as you say, your imagination?

Comment: @lit No, it actually happens intermittently

Comment: Please copy and paste the error output into the question.

Comment: @lit Just added the error message